# Active Storage Direct Upload is removing the file input during upload w/Simple Form - Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I managed to get direct uploads working with simple_form gem, using an input options helper method. The issue I am having, is that starting a direct upload will cause the progress bar to show in place of the file input and I am unable to re-upload another file if that file input has the wrong file attached. Essentially, I am trying to replace files that may have been uploaded - after the fact. **How can I stop direct upload from replacing the file input with the progress bar?**

**direct_upload_file_input.rb**

```
class DirectUploadFileInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::FileInput 
 def input_html_options
  super.merge({direct_upload: true})
 end 
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
has_one :media_file

  <%= f.input :media_file, as: :file, input_html: {:onchange => "activate_progress_bar", direct_upload: true}, label: false %>
```

**direct_upload.js**

// direct_uploads.js

```
addEventListener("direct-upload:initialize", event => {
  const { target, detail } = event
  const { id, file } = detail
  target.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", `
    <div id="direct-upload-${id}" class="direct-upload direct-upload--pending">
      <div id="direct-upload-progress-${id}" class="direct-upload__progress" style="width: 0%"></div>
      <span class="direct-upload__filename"></span>
    </div>
  `)
  target.previousElementSibling.querySelector(`.direct-upload__filename`).textContent = file.name
})

addEventListener("direct-upload:start", event => {
  const { id } = event.detail
  const element = document.getElementById(`direct-upload-${id}`)
  element.classList.remove("direct-upload--pending")
})

addEventListener("direct-upload:progress", event => {
  const { id, progress } = event.detail
  const progressElement = document.getElementById(`direct-upload-progress-${id}`)
  progressElement.style.width = `${progress}%`
})

addEventListener("direct-upload:error", event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const { id, error } = event.detail
  const element = document.getElementById(`direct-upload-${id}`)
  element.classList.add("direct-upload--error")
  element.setAttribute("title", error)
})

addEventListener("direct-upload:end", event => {
  const { id } = event.detail
  const element = document.getElementById(`direct-upload-${id}`)
  element.classList.add("direct-upload--complete")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `direct-upload:initialize` method you're replacing the `target` with the progress bar div. The `target` in this case is set to the `event.target` which is your file input field. You need to replace or insert the progress bar on a different page element if you want to keep the file input but also display the progress bar. Something like...

```
let progress = document.getElementById('progress');
progress.innerHTML =
  `<div id="direct-upload-${id}" class="direct-upload direct-upload--pending">
    <div id="direct-upload-progress-${id}" class="direct-upload__progress" style="width: 0%"></div>
    <span class="direct-upload__filename"></span>
  </div>`
```